# Spacy - Convert Token type into list

Tags: python-3.x, list, token, spacy

I have few elements which I got after performing operation in spacy having type
Input -

```
li = ['India', 'Australia', 'Brazil']
for i in li:
    print(type(i))
```

Output:

> `<class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>`
>
> `<class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>`
>
> `<class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>`

I want to make all elements in list with str type for iteration.
Expected output -

```
li = ['India', 'Australia', 'Brazil']
for i in li:
    print(type(i))
```

Output

> `<class 'str'>`
>
> `<class 'str'>`
>
> `<class 'str'>`

please suggest some optimized way..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spacy Token has a [attribute called `text`](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes).
Here's a complete example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
t = (u"India Australia Brazil")
li = nlp(t)
for i in li:
    print(i.text)
```

or if you want the list of tokens as list of strings:

```
list_of_strings  = [i.text for i in li]
```

Comment: No you got me wrong. I have already list of that after some operation i performed using spacy. I want to convert that token into string now. Is there any way for that.?

Comment: `i.text` gives the string representation of the token. Isn't that what you need ? covert token to string ??

Comment: Exactly. converting list of tokens into list of string. Let me try this for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution and for sharing your knowledge. It works very well to convert a spacy doc/span to a string or list of strings to further use them in string operations.

you can also use this:-

```
    for i in li:
        print(str(i))
```